# Special characters get an additional character Â while posting from tiny editor

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I am using tiny editor from scriptny (Not TinyMCE editor) to get and post html formatted data from users.The problem is with special characters .It seems tiny editor is adding a Â before special characters like © or it is not using utf-8 while posting data.I have used plain text area with same form and everything works fine(that means whole chain from form to jsp to database is utf-8 ) but with tiny editor there is a problem ,How can i convert data from tiny editor to utf-8 format

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is a common fileupload problem in java and not tiny editor problem as without common file upload the problem disappeared